# Uploading a file from web-based platform to S3 bucket using NodeJS - Callback Hell

Tags: javascript, node.js

This code checks user permissions for uploading file, and if user can upload, then the file undergoes a check to see if it exists in SharePoint. If so then the file is pulled and uploaded to S3 bucket. This all works fine, but I have been told all these catches create callback hell. I've been trying to implement promises but I am very confused on how to change these callbacks to promises. Appreciate any help.

```
//////////////////
// Dependencies //
//////////////////
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const ping = require('tcp-ping');
const Semaphore = require('mysql-semaphore');
const dateFormat = require('dateformat');
const randomstring = require("randomstring");
const rimraf = require("rimraf");
const docx4js = require('docx4js');

var sppull = require("sppull").sppull;
const storage = require('azure-storage');


///////////////////////////////
// Sequelize database models //
///////////////////////////////
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../util/database');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
const ProjectContacts = sequelize.import('../models/db/project_contact');


////////////////////////
// Local dependencies //
////////////////////////
const { parseJsonFile, encrypt, makeDirs, waitForLock, pullFromSharePoint, decrypt, doesFileExistSp } = require('../util/common');
const { getNormalizedFilepath, updateTAndCCleanup, convertDocxToHtml, insertNewTCVersion, waitForFileUpload } = require('../util/update-t-and-c-helper');
const { listContainers, createContainer, uploadString, uploadLocalFile, listBlobs, downloadBlob } = require('../util/blob-helper');
const createError = require('../util/error-management').createErrorFlow;
const { getProjectPath, saveMetadata, copyFileSpToS3Cleanup } = require('../util/copy-to-s3-helper');
const { getTimeTaken, formatLockKey, saveFileToSp, createFolderIfNotExists, createFolderPathRecursively, processExcelFileRequest } = require('../util/common');
const logger = require('../util/logger')(module);
```

```
const fileName = req.body.fileName.trim();
const spSite = req.body.spSite;
const spFolder = req.body.spFolder;
const email = req.body.email_address;
const downloadPath = req.body.S3Path;
const spFile = `${spFolder}/${fileName}`;
const before = Date.now();
const uploadFolderName = 'upload';
const siteUrl = `${process.env.SP_URL}/sites/${spSite}/`;
const creds = {
    username: process.env.SP_USER,
    password: decrypt(process.env.SP_PASSWORD)
};
```

```
ProjectContacts.findAll({ where: { can_upload_files: 1, email_address: email }, attributes: ['email_address', 'project_id', 'can_upload_files'] })
        .then(projectContacts => {
            if (projectContacts.length > 0) {   //If email can upload, proceed
                doesFileExistSp(creds, spSite, siteUrl, spFile) //Check if file exists in SharePoint
                    .then(exists => {
                        if (exists) {
                            logger.info(`DOWNLOAD PATH: ${downloadPath}`);
                            logger.info(`FILENAME: ${fileName}`);
                            const sppullContext = {
                                siteUrl: siteUrl, //SharePoint URL
                                creds: {
                                    username: process.env.SP_USER,
                                    password: decrypt(process.env.SP_PASSWORD)
                                }
                            };
                            const sppullOptions = {
                                spRootFolder: spFolder,      // The folder path for the file in SharePoint
                                dlRootFolder: downloadPath,  // Where the file is saved locally
                                strictObjects: [fileName],  // Only download the fileName specified as a query parameter
                                muteConsole: true
                            };
                            pullFromSharePoint(sppullContext, sppullOptions)
                                .then(filepath => {     //Pull file with fileName from SharePoint
                                    logger.info(`FILE NOW IN PATH: ${filepath}`);
                                    // Create the upload directory within the project directory.
                                    const s3UploadFolder = path.join(downloadPath, uploadFolderName);
                                    makeDirs(s3UploadFolder)
                                        .then(() => {   //creates upload folder in s3
                                            function saveMetadataCallback(errorObj) {  //callback for saveMetadata which checks for errors, semaphore/locks not being used
                                                if (errorObj) {
                                                    const filepath = path.join(downloadPath, fileName);
                                                    copyFileSpToS3Cleanup(filepath, semaphore, lockKey).then(() => {
                                                        const error = createError(errorObj.errorMsg, errorObj.statusCode, errorObj.origErr);
                                                        return next(errorObj);
                                                    }).catch(errorObj => {
                                                        const error = createError(errorObj.errorMsg, errorObj.statusCode, errorObj.origErr);
                                                        return next(error);
                                                    });
                                                }
                                            }
                                            saveMetadata(saveMetadataCallback); // Save the metadata info.json files.
                                        }).catch(err => {
                                            const filepath = path.join(downloadPath, fileName);
                                            copyFileSpToS3Cleanup(filepath, semaphore, lockKey)
                                                .then(() => {
                                                    const error = createError('Unable to create upload directory', 500, err);
                                                    return next(error);
                                                }).catch(errorObj => {
                                                    const error = createError(errorObj.errorMsg, errorObj.statusCode, errorObj.origErr);
                                                    return next(error);
                                                });
                                        });
                                    return res.status(200).json({
                                        message: `${fileName} has been uploaded to ${filepath}`
                                    })
                                }).catch(errorObj => {
                                    const filepath = path.join(downloadPath, fileName);
                                    copyFileSpToS3Cleanup(filepath, semaphore, lockKey)
                                        .then(() => {
                                            const error = createError(errorObj.errorMsg, errorObj.statusCode, errorObj.origErr);
                                            return next(error);
                                        }).catch(errorObj => {
                                            const error = createError(errorObj.errorMsg, errorObj.statusCode, errorObj.origErr);
                                            return next(error);
                                        });
                                });
                        } else {
                            const error = createError('File does not exist!');
                            return next(error);
                        }
                    }).catch(err => {
                        const error = createError('File does not exist!');
                        return next(error);
                    })
            } else {
                logger.error(`${email} does not have permission to upload`);
                return res.status(401).json({
                    message: `${email} does not have permission to upload`
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you add your requires in there? Otherwise it will be hard to know what functions you wrote, and what functions you call from 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Show the whole module file. The code context is important here.

Comment: Added. Let me know if I should add some of the local dependencies code, to clarify it even more.

Comment: Almost spit out my coffee when I saw `creds.password`, then I saw it was fine

Comment: lol! I'm being extra careful to not post the credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it using promises:

```
//Finds if project_contact email has permission to upload
    function findProjectContacts() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            ProjectContacts.findAll({ where: { can_upload_files: 1, email_address: email }, attributes: ['email_address', 'project_id', 'can_upload_files'] })
                .then(projectContacts => {
                    if (projectContacts.length > 0) {
                        return resolve(true);
                    }
                    else {
                        const error = createError(`${email} does not have permission to upload!`, 401);
                        return reject(error);
                    }
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    const error = createError(`${email} does not have permission to upload!`, 401, err);
                    return reject(error)
                })
        })
    }

    //Checks if file exists in SharePoint
    function findFile() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            doesFileExistSp(creds, spSite, siteUrl, spFile).then(exists => {
                if (!exists) {
                    const error = createError(`${filename} does not exist in ${spFolder}`, 404);
                    return reject(error);
                } else {
                    return resolve(true);
                }
            }).catch(err => {
                const error = createError(`${filename} does not exist in ${spFolder} `, 404, err);
                return reject(error);
            });
        });
    }

    //Pulls file from SharePoint to download into specified filepath
    function pullFile() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const sppullContext = {
                siteUrl: siteUrl, //SharePoint URL
                creds: creds
            };
            const sppullOptions = {
                spRootFolder: spFolder,      // The folder path for the file in SharePoint
                dlRootFolder: downloadPath,  // Where the file is saved locally
                strictObjects: [filename],  // Only download the filename specified as a query parameter
                muteConsole: true
            };
            pullFromSharePoint(sppullContext, sppullOptions)      //Pull file with filename from SharePoint
                .then(filepath => {
                    if (!fs.existsSync(filepath)) {
                        const error = createError(`${filepath} does not exist`, 404);
                        return reject(error);
                    }
                    else {
                        logger.info(`FILE NOW IN PATH: ${filepath}`);
                        const s3UploadFolder = path.join(downloadPath, uploadFolderName);
                        makeDirs(s3UploadFolder);

                    }
                    return resolve(true);
                });
        });
    }

    findProjectContacts()
        .then(permission => {
            if (permission === true)
                return findFile();
        })
        .then(fileFound => {
            if (fileFound === true)
                return pullFile();
        }).then(fileCopied => {
            if (fileCopied === true)
                logger.info(`${filename} has been uploaded`);
            return res.status(200).json({
                message: `${filename} has been uploaded`
            });
        }).catch(errorObj => {
            return next(errorObj);
        })
}
```